# Progressive Web App Authenticate to API

Tags: javascript-framework, progressive-web-apps

Usually when I build a new website I create a .NET or PHP website. These website either connect to a MySQL DB or an external API. To do this I can securely store my credentials to these services and the back end will authenticate to them. Now since I want to build a Progressive Web App which is front-end only, how can I securely auth to these? Does my PWA have to have a login page that returns an API key that is dynamic? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Progressive Web App (PWA) **is not front-end only**. You can see the [definition](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) and the [PWA Baseline](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/checklist) too clearly understand what makes a PWA.

The problem you have mention is authentication on Single Page Web apps (which is front-end only). Here is the first article from Google with keyword "Single page web app authentication".

[Token Based Authentication for Single Page Apps](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-spa)

Comment: Single Page Web App is not front-end only neither.